# Python peewee: How to select distinct values on one column before a join?

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I try to join a second table (PageLikes) on a first Table (PageVisits) after selecting only distinct values on one column of the first table with the python ORM peewee.

In pure SQL I can do this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(pagevisits.visitor_id), pagelikes.liked_item FROM pagevisits
INNER JOIN pagelikes on pagevisits.visitor_id = pagelikes.user_id
```

In peewee with python I have tried:

```py
query = (Page.select(
         fn.Distinct(Pagevisits.visitor_id),
         PageLikes.liked_item)
         .join(PageLIkes)
```

This gives me an error:
`distinct() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

The only way I can and have used distinct with peewee is like this:

```py
query = (Page.select(
         Pagevisits.visitor_id,
         PageLikes.liked_item)
         .distinct()
```

which does not seem to work for my scenario.

So how can I select only distinct values in one table based on one column before I join another table with peewee?

Comment: Have you tried `query = (Page.select(
         Pagevisits.visitor_id.distinct(),
         PageLikes.liked_item)` ?

Comment: This seems to translate it into a distinct statement but yields another error:
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT `t3`.`visitor_id` FROM `pagevisits` AS `t3` INNER JOIN `pagelikes` AS' at line 1")

Comment: What are you trying to figure out? Your query doesn't make sense to me -- what is the meaning of a distinct user id w/an arbitrary liked item id?

Comment: For a page or some pages I want to know: What did the users like? I don't want to count a user twice in case the user visited more than one page or one page multiple times. I suggested an answer to that question. Maybe you can verify that?

Comment: You should have no problems running `fn.DISTINCT(pagevisits.visitor_id)`. Can you share the full traceback? I'm able to run that w/o problems locally.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you should be encountering an error using `fn.DISTINCT()` in that way. I'm curious to see the full traceback. In my testing locally, I have no problems running something like:

```
query = (PageVisits
         .select(fn.DISTINCT(PageVisits.visitor_id), PageLikes.liked_item)
         .join(PageLikes))
```

Which produces SQL equivalent to what you're after. I'm using the latest peewee code btw.

Answer (score 0):

As [Papooch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4429729/papooch) suggested, calling distinct on the Model seems to work:

```
distinct_visitors = (Pagevisits
                            .select(
                                Pagevisits.visitor_id.distinct().alias("visitor")
                            )
                            .where(Pagevisits.page_id == "Some specifc page")
                            .alias('distinct_visitors')
                            )


query = (Pagelikes
         .select(fn.Count(Pagelikes.liked_item),
         )
         .join(distinct_visitors, on=(distinct_visitors.c.visitor = Pagelikes.user_id))
         .group_by(Pagelikes.liked_item)
         )
```